# my 2.2.6 magento checkout page do not display firstname,postcode,and telephone input field

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.2.6, requirejs

My current version is `magento 2.2.6` and i am facing a strange issue.

> My checkout page do not display firstname,postcode,and telephone input
>   field on checkout page.

whenever i try to place order it gives message

> "firstname and telephone are required field".

I have disabled all custom extensions and default checkout method is also not displaying those fields.
what should i do to display those fields in checkout page.
Any one help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove below folders from your project.

rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
rm -rf generated/
rm -rf var/cache var/composer_home var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed

after that run below command lines:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Why we need to deploy the static files two times?